# How can I set the MIME type upon writing a file to google cloud storage

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage, blobstore

I am saving a wav and an mp3 file to google cloud storage (rather than blobstore) as per the [instructions](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/#Python_Using_the_Blobstore_API_with_Google_Cloud_Storage). However, in doing so the MIME type of the file is lost and instead it is converted to `binary/octet-stream` which unfortunately breaks the apps I'm working with.

1. How can I set the MIME type upon writing the file?
2. Is there a way to set the MIME type automatically based on the file i.e. if it's an mp3 file it gets saved as audio/mpeg and if wav its audio/wav?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example:

```
def gcs_write_blob(dyn, blob):
    """ update google cloud storage dyn entity """

    gcs_file_name = '/%s/%s' % (default_bucket, dyn.filename)

    content_type = mimetypes.guess_type(dyn.filename)[0]
    if dyn.extension in ['js', 'css']:
        content_type += b'; charset=utf-8'

    with gcs.open(gcs_file_name, 'w', content_type=content_type,
                  options={b'x-goog-acl': b'public-read'}) as f:
        f.write(blob)

    return gcs_file_name
```

Taken from this gist: https://gist.github.com/voscausa/9541133

Answer (score 0):

The [BlobInfo](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/blobinfoclass) class has a "content_type" field that you can use to set the mime type of the object.